# undo a setFlags ItemIsUserCheckable

Tags: python, qt, checkbox

I created a QListWidget and I want to make its elements checkable only at particular places in the application (I need it for a particular application where the user select a principal element on the list while clicking on it and then select secondary elements while checking their boxes).
Im ok with making the elements checkable but I can't find a solution to undo this and remove the checkboxes... I did this :

```
for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
         item=self.listWidget.item(i)
         item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
         item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

but then I struggle... I tried :

```
tmp=self.listWidget.takeItem(i)
self.listWidget.addItem(tmp)
```

But the item come back with its checkbox :(
I could simply destroy the item and then put it back again but this can be a kind of heavy treatment ! Is there any solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To Remove a flag try:

```
item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
```

^^ `item` is the element you want to unFlag. In simple terms `^` operator works as the opposite to `|` and thus excludes the `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` flag from the existing flags that `item.flags()` returns

**Update:**

While the above code will disable the checkable feature, to completely hide the checkbox try

```
item.setData(Qt::CheckStateRole, QVariant());
```

Do note that this does not preserve the state of the checkbox after this call is made.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It partially worked. It made my item uncheckable but I still got the display of a checkbox in my QListWidget (which can be confusing for the user). Do you have a solution to remove that too ?

Comment: Updated my answer to show a way to hide the checkbox as well(It's actually a remove than a hide. Hide feature does not exist for this without subclassing and doing it yourself.)

Comment: @Viv I know i am late for this question, but what does `.setFlags` ?

Comment: @Hiatus not really sure I follow your question. Are you asking what `setFlags()` function does? if so it just sets an enum [Qt::ItemFlag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) to represent a particular property for the control.